# upgrading angular - now it can't find my controllers

Tags: angularjs

I've upgraded Angular to version 1.3x from 1.0x and now I'm getting a really nasty bug:

> Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'LayoutController' is not a function, got
>   undefined

Maybe someone could help spot the issue? I have read through a bunch of SO posts and can't seem to see why it isn't able to find the issue.

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="AngularFlask">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Yada</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/bootstrap-responsive.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/bootstrap-theme.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/main.css">

    <script src="/static/lib/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/lib/angular-resource/angular-resource.js"></script>
  <script src="/static/lib/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/js/controllers.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/js/services.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/js/directives.js"></script>

    <script src="/static/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">YADA (yet another dating app)</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Menu<span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Matches</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Vouches</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
<div ng-controller="LayoutController" ng-init='init({{ instagram_url|tojson }})'/>

    <div class="container page">
        <div id="content" class="container main" ng-view>
        </div>

        <hr>
        <footer id="footer" class="footer">
            <div class="footer-left">
                <a href="/about">About</a> |
                <a href="/">Home</a>
            </div>
            <div class="footer-right">
                <span>&copy; 2014 Indigo Panda Labs Inc.</span>
            </div>
        </footer>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

app.js

```
var app = angular.module('AngularFlask', ['angularFlaskServices', 'ngRoute'])
    .config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider',
        function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
        $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'static/partials/landing.html',
            controller: IndexController
        })
        .when('/about', {
            templateUrl: 'static/partials/about.html',
            controller: AboutController
        })
        .when('/instagram_oauth_callback', {
            templateUrl: 'static/partials/profile.html',
            controller: ProfileController
        })
        .when('/likes', {
            templateUrl: 'static/partials/likes.html',
            controller: LikesController
        })
        .when('/basicinfo', {
            templateUrl: 'static/partials/basicinfo.html',
            controller: BasicInfoController
        })
        .when('/workandschool', {
            templateUrl: 'static/partials/workandschool.html',
            controller: WorkAndSchoolController
        })

//      .otherwise({
//          redirectTo: '/'
//      })
        ;

        $locationProvider.html5Mode({
        enabled: true,
        requireBase: false
        });
    }])
;

app.config(['$interpolateProvider', function($interpolateProvider) {
      $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('{[');
      $interpolateProvider.endSymbol(']}');
    }]);

/* Controllers */

//Tab order:
//  landing
//  instagram callback
//  pics
//  basic info
//  work and school
//  likes
//  request vouches
//  view profile

function LayoutController($scope) {
    $scope.init = function(instagram_url) {
        $scope.instagram_url = instagram_url;
    }
}

function IndexController($scope, $http) {

} 

function WorkAndSchoolController($scope) {
    $scope.isSelectedWorkEducationInputType = false;

    $scope.connectManually = function() {
        $scope.isSelectedWorkEducationInputType = true;
    };

    $scope.connectToLinkedIn = function() {
        console.log("stub to connect to linkedin");
        $scope.isSelectedWorkEducationInputType = true;
    }

    $scope.goToLikes
}


function LikesController($scope, $window) {
    console.log("hi")
    $scope.likes = [{"id" : 1,
                     "caption" : "Hot air balooning",
                     "isSelected" : false},
                    {"id" : 2,
                     "caption" : "Skiing", 
                     "isSelected" : false},
                    {"id" : 3,
                     "caption" : "Wine tasting",
                     "isSelected" : false},
                     {"id" : 4,
                         "caption" : "Kiteboarding",
                         "isSelected" : false},
                        {"id" : 5,
                         "caption" : "Bar hopping", 
                         "isSelected" : false},
                        {"id" : 6,
                         "caption" : "Bacon",
                         "isSelected" : false},
                         {"id" : 7,
                             "caption" : "Backpacking",
                             "isSelected" : false},
                            {"id" : 8,
                             "caption" : "Gastro pubs", 
                             "isSelected" : false},
                            {"id" : 9,
                             "caption" : "Gossip Girl",
                             "isSelected" : false}]
        $scope.isError = false;
        $scope.goToWorkAndSchool = function() {
                  if ($scope.myForm.$valid == true) {
                          console.log("valid form");
                          console.log("")
                          $window.location.href = "/workandschool"
                  } else {
                          console.log("invalid form");
                          $scope.error_text = "Error, all fields are required!"
                      $scope.isError = true; 
                  }
        }
}

function LandingController($scope, $window) {
    $scope.instagramLogin = function () {
        $window.location.href = $scope.instagram_url
    };
}


function BasicInfoController($scope, $window) {
  $scope.isError = false;
  $scope.goToLikes = function() {
      if ($scope.myForm.$valid == true) {
          console.log("valid form");
          console.log("")
          $window.location.href = "/likes"
      } else {
          console.log("invalid form");
          $scope.error_text = "Error, all fields are required!"
          $scope.isError = true; 
      }
  }
}

function AboutController($scope) {

}

function ProfileController($scope, $http, $window) {
    $http.get('api/pic/').
    success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      $scope.pics = data;
      console.log("loaded images")

    }).
    error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      // log error
    });

    $scope.selectedImages = [];

    $scope.clickImage = function(index, url) {
        if (index in $scope.selectedImages) {
            delete $scope.selectedImages[index]
        } else {
            $scope.selectedImages[index] = url;
        }
    }

    $scope.getSelectedImage = function(imageNum) {
        return $scope.selectedImages[Object.keys($scope.selectedImages)[imageNum]]  
    }

    $scope.goToBasicInfo = function() { $window.location.href = "/basicinfo" };
}
```

Comment: are these controllers only defined once, in a controllers.js file? or are they defined at the bottom of the app.js as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Angular.JS 1.3 you have to define controllers with the `angular.module("whatever").controller("controllerName", TheFunction)` syntax. You will have to go for each function and add a similar line (if you want to keep the definitions untouched, otherwise, just wrap them in `controller()` calls).

Here's a post that talks about this very problem when it was first introduced in one of Angular 1.3 betas:

[My Angular App is Broken after Upgrading to the Latest Beta](http://michaelcrump.net/my-angular-app-was-just-working)

Answer (score 3):

Angular [moved away](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#breaking-changes-15) from globally declared controllers. To declare a controller, use:

```
app.controller("LayoutController", LayoutController);
```

or, if you want to minify, identify the dependencies directly:

Alternative 1:

```
app.controller("LayoutController", ["$scope", LayoutController]);
```

Alternative 2:

```
LayoutController.$inject = ["$scope"];
app.controller("LayoutController", LayoutController);
```